# How to efficiently repeat a function on a data set in R?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a function `funToRepeat`:

```
funToRepeat <- function(df){
    rows <- nrow(df)
    cols <- ncol(df)
    err <- runif( rows * cols )
    dfNew <- df + as.data.frame( matrix(err, nrow=rows, ncol=cols) )
    dfNew
}
```

I want to operate `funToRepeat` on `dfTest` (a toy data set), multiple times, say `n`.

```
dfTest <-
  structure(list(V1 = 1:2, V2 = 3:4), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), 
  row.names = c(NA,-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

How would I do this and average the `n` outputs of `funToRepeat` in `R`, efficiently?

A very bad example with `n=10` may be:

```
dfAvg <- as.data.frame(list(V1=c(0, 0), V2=c(0, 0)))
for(i in 1:10){
    dfAvg <- dfAvg + funToRepeat(dfTest)
}
dfAvg <- dfAvg/10
```

Please notice, I am not trying to bootstrap. I want to operate `funToRepeat` on my data set and take the average of the `n` outputs. I want to do this as I am adding `err`, a random term, to my data.frame and want to provide a reasonable answer. (I am not doing exactly this in real life, but something very similar)

Comment: if efficiency is the only problem, I would consider Rcpp...

Comment: @teucer. I agree, I am a very happy and statisfied Rcpp user. But I was looking for an R-ish way of doing this. It would be good to see the magnitude of speed-up Rcpp provides.

Comment: maybe than you can store your values in a 3d array and use `rowMeans` (which is implemented in `C` I believe, so should be fast)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I for one would put everything to the list and then use `Reduce`.

```
funToRepeat <- function(dims) {
    err <- runif(prod(dims))
    matrix(err,nrow=dims[1],ncol=dims[2]) 
}

ll <- alply(cbind(rep(10,10),rep(20,10)),1,funToRepeat)

sum.ll <- Reduce("+",ll)
```

Then convert to data.frame you need after dividing by length of the list to get the average.

Note that your function does not need whole of a `data.frame` to operate, only its dimensions. The conversion to data.frame is unnecessary cost here, so it is better not to use it.

Comment: (+1) I did not know conversion to data.frame is costly. This was a toy example, but my data set has 1e4 rows. Thanks.

Comment: @suncoolsu, I do not know how exactly costly it is. I added the comment purely on the ground that any unnecessary operation is costly. On the other hand data.frame is special type in R, so there surely is additional cost of converting to it, not withstanding that passing the object to the function is effectively creating additional copy, so if speed is required this  should be preferably avoided.